# MYSQL: LIKE (subquery) returning many rows

Tags: mysql, subquery, rows, sql-like

The following code work's properly.

```
SELECT Message
FROM SystemEventsR
WHERE Message
LIKE CONCAT('%',(SELECT username FROM users LIMIT 1),'%')
```

My question though, is most of the time i need to return more than one row.

I omit the LIMIT which results to an 'Error Code 1242'

Why is this?

I need all messages which contain at least one username

I also used a JOIN but to no avail

```
SELECT Message
FROM SystemEventsR
JOIN users ON Message LIKE CONCAT('%',(SELECT username FROM users),'%')
```

I would like something like the following, but the number of rows in users table is not constant

```
SELECT Message
FROM SystemEventsR
WHERE 
Message LIKE CONCAT('%',(SELECT username FROM users LIMIT 1,1),'%') OR
Message LIKE CONCAT('%',(SELECT username FROM users LIMIT 2,1),'%') OR
Message LIKE CONCAT('%',(SELECT username FROM users LIMIT 3,1),'%')
```

Comment: Are you trying to get all messages with a valid username in them? If so you want a join.

Comment: yes, i need all messages which contain at least one username. With a join I face a hard time with the "ON" part. Can you please give an example?

Comment: is there any column `user id` in `SystemEventsR` ?

Comment: To join two tables, you need to have a common column which will be the condition of ON . That's why I want to know the previous question

Comment: No, unfortunately, there isnt any common column between the two tables (SystemEventsR and users)

Comment: I guess, it is not possible to join in that case where there is no foreign key between these two tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not simply;

```
SELECT Message 
FROM SystemEventsR s
JOIN users u
  ON s.Message LIKE CONCAT('%',u.username,'%')
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2cc93/3).

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
SELECT Message
FROM SystemEventsR
WHERE Message
RLIKE (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(username SEPARATOR '|') FROM users)
```

Check the manual regarding [RLIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html) .